# What is wrong when using System.set property in java?

Tags: java, settings, fortify

In my java program, I'm using `System.set` property, and it's working fine. But in my whole project, I'm not using any `System.get` property. But when I use Hp fortify tool, it's showing bug as **Setting  Manipulation**. Set property using like this :`System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");` is it wrong way to use,if so can anybody guide me.

Comment: could you please tell me why vote down?

Comment: It is not wrong to set system property in your code but it is not the best way. System class is meant to access externally defined properties. May be that is why your hp tool is showing a code bug. Hope this helps. And by the way I didnt down vote

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating system settings from the Java code is a potential security issue. See the [description of the alert here](http://www.hpenterprisesecurity.com/vulncat/en/vulncat/cpp/setting_manipulation.html). Here's a brief extract of the document:

> ABSTRACT
>
> Allowing external control of system settings can disrupt service or cause an application to behave in unexpected ways.
>
> EXPLANATION
>
> Setting manipulation vulnerabilities occur when an attacker can control values that govern the behavior of the system, manage specific resources, or in some way affect the functionality of the application.
>
> Because setting manipulation covers a diverse set of functions, any attempt at illustrating it will inevitably be incomplete. Rather than searching for a tight-knit relationship between the functions addressed in the setting manipulation category, take a step back and consider the sorts of system values that an attacker should not be allowed to control.